# Haskell- return True if key is in associative list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function that accepts a String as parameter and returns a boolean `True` if the String exists as a key value in the following associative list:

```
lis = [("Kingston", [12.2, 17.3, 9.1]), ("Ottawa", [10.0, 13.9, 8.2])]
```

This is my function, I want to be able to do this using list comprehension if possible:

```
check :: String -> [(String,a)] -> Bool
check val alist
    | [ key | (key,num)<-alist, key==val] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

The error I get, if it helps, is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[String]’
```

Can someone show me what my mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In haskell, guards should evaluate to a boolean value. So, something like this will work:

```
check :: String -> [(String,a)] -> Bool
check val alist
    | length [ key | (key,num) <-alist, key==val] >= 1 = True
    | otherwise = False
```

But note that this will have to traverse the entire list.

Whereas in the following code it doesn't have to traverse the entire list and is more efficient:

```
check :: String -> [(String,a)] -> Bool
check val alist
    | efficientCheck [ key | (key,num) <-alist, key==val] = True
    | otherwise = False

efficientCheck :: [a] -> Bool
efficientCheck (x:xs) = True
efficientCheck _ = False
```

Demo:

```
λ> check "bye" [("hi",3)]
False
λ> check "hi" [("hi",3),("bye",4)]
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a list comprehension that is of type `[String]` in a guard where a `Bool` is expected.

What you need to do is check whether that list comprehension is empty or not.  Using, for example, `null`.

```
check :: String -> [(String,a)] -> Bool
check val alist = not $ null [ key | (key,num) <- alist, key==val ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression in a guard clause has to evaluate to a `Bool`.  This isn't Python, it doesn't happen automatically.  Try

```
check val alist
    | not $ null [key | (key, num) <- alist, key == val] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

But this can be written simpler as simply

```
check val alist = not $ null [key | (key, num) <- alist, key == val]
```

Since the guard is just checking if a value is `True` or `False`.